# Howto reboot system after systemd unit started?

Tags: systemd, reboot

On Ubuntu 16 Xenial (systemd version 229) I have the following systemd service:

```
[Unit]
Description=Example unit
Documentation=man:apt(8)
ConditionACPower=true
After=apt-daily.service

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=echo foobar
KillMode=process
TimeoutStopSec=900
```

Now, I want the operating system to reboot after the above service was started, regardless if the start succeeded or failed.

How can I achieve that?

Edit:

I created a reboot service file `/etc/systemd/system/my-reboot.service`

```
[Unit]
Description=Reboot
RefuseManualStart=true

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStartPre=/bin/sleep 30
ExecStart=/sbin/reboot
```

And added to the OP service "Example unit":

```
[Unit]
Wants=my-reboot.service
Before=my-reboot.service
```

In a first test this worked: 30 seconds after "Example unit" started, the system reboots. Is this a good aproach?

Comment: Do you have this file? `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/50unattended-upgrades`

Comment: The question about the file `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/50unattended-upgrades` is absolutely off topic. (btw that file exists and unattended-upgrades works)

Comment: Its not of-topic if you need to set `//Unattended-Upgrade::Automatic-Reboot "false";` to `true` which exists in that file.  The reason I asked was to make sure it existed, not to dispute whether Automatic Upgrades were working or not.  See also: [Set Up Automatic Security Update (Unattended Upgrades) on Ubuntu](https://www.linuxbabe.com/ubuntu/automatic-security-update-unattended-upgrades-ubuntu)

Comment: I want reboot also if there was no new package at all (so unattended-upgrades did not do anything). As I have said I want the reboot even if unattended-upgrades exited with failure for whatever reason. If it is clearer to you, you in the service there could also be `ExecStart=echo foo` it does not matter what the service does.

Comment: You might be overthinking this: If Unattended Upgrades did nothing, you won't need a reboot.  Try setting `Unattended-Upgrade::Automatic-Reboot-Time` to `now` and see if it will reboot even with partial failure.  If the unattended-upgrades package itself is ever upgraded you'll wipe out whatever modification you make to the file.

Comment: I edited my OP to make clear this has nothing to do with unattended upgrades.